# SQL Optional JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    invoice.id         "Invoice ID",
    account.name       "Owner"
FROM
    invoice
LEFT OUTER JOIN account 
    on invoice.customerid = account.id
```

However, the invoice.customerid may be an account or a contact. That's determined by another field, the customertype, in the invoice table.

So how can I change my JOIN to JOIN to different tables for each row based on the value of another column?

Using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Please do tag sql server

Comment: I think UNION or UNION ALL would be the way to go here

Comment: This is (obviously) a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that there is another table 'contact' which you will need to join to and that you want to only return the account name or contact name depending on the value of the customertype column. I made the assumption that customertype is a string that may be either 'account' or 'contact' below:

```
SELECT
    invoice.id 'Invoice ID',
    CASE invoice.customertype  
      WHEN 'account' THEN account.name
      WHEN 'contact' THEN contact.name   
    END 'Owner'
FROM
    invoice
LEFT OUTER JOIN account 
    ON invoice.customerid = account.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN contact
    ON invoice.customerid = contact.id
```

Comment: In the case of a contact and account having the same id, this approach would join to a wrong row, so you would never want to select a column from either account or contact without that CASE statement

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
SELECT i.id as Invoice_ID,
       COALESCE(a.name, c.name) as Owner
FROM invoice i LEFT JOIN
     account a
     ON i.customerid = a.id AND i.customerType = 'Account' LEFT JOIN
     contact c
     ON i.customerid = c.id AND i.customerType = 'Contact';
```

Note that this incorporates the `customerType` logic into the `ON` clauses.  This should make the `JOIN`s more accurate.

Comment: Yes this seems like the same approach as mine below, but cleaner.  I don't like the idea of carrying around the wrong info from an inaccurate join.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a CASE in the join condition

```
    SELECT invoice.id   "Invoice ID",
       IsNull(account.NAME,contact.NAME) "Owner"
    FROM   invoice
       LEFT OUTER JOIN account
                    ON account.id = CASE
                                      WHEN invoice.customertype = 'Account'
                                        THEN invoice.customerid
                                      ELSE NULL
                                    END 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN contact
                    ON contact.id = CASE
                                      WHEN invoice.customertype = 'contact'
                                        THEN invoice.customerid
                                      ELSE NULL
                                    END
```